# Cross domain Reques blocked - Even access control allow origin already setup

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to access some thrid party urls using Ajax. The API has hosted on some server (myapiserver.com) and I am trying to access the api using the following code from my development server (dev.example.com)

**PLEASE NOTE: Already from  myapiserver Access-Control-Allow-Origin set as "development server domain names (dev.example.com, example.com)"**
But still I am getting errors as follows, Is there any parameters I need to set up ?

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json"},
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'https://myapiserver.com/university/search',
    data: JSON.stringify({"universityName":"oxford"}),
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {

        console.log(data);

    },
    error: function(result) {
      alert("Error");
    } });
```

And I am getting error as follows :

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myapiserver.com/university/search. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'https://dev.example.com, https://www.example.com').**

Comment: Can you post your server configuration for allowing those domains? Problem should be there.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see the headers sent by the request

Comment: @ClaudioRedi its the third party server and we are not managing this, They just allowed our domains...